# Are all finite fields isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_p$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

I've recently started taking some algebra courses and I was wondering whether or not every finite field is isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_p$, where $p$ is prime.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field#Some_small_finite_fields

Comment: I also tried to put the basics into our [tag wiki](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/finite-fields/info) on finite-fields.

Comment: [A possibly interesting blog article about fields with $2^n$ elements](http://blog.plover.com/math/z2.html)

Answer (score 23):

No. But every finite field is isomorphic to $$F_{p^n}$$ for a prime $p$ and a positive integer $n$. In particular, the finite field with $p^n$ elements is the splitting field of the polynomial

$$x^{p^n} - x$$

over $F_p$. There's a full Wikipedia article [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field) about these.

Answer (score 20):

You're close, every finite field is isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$, which is a quotient of $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ by an irreducible polynomial of degree $n$.  It's often difficult to see that things like this can exist without a concrete example.  The easiest is $\mathbb{F}_4$:

$$\begin{array}{c|cccc}
+       &   0       &   1       &   \alpha  &   1+\alpha\\ \hline
0       &   0       &   1       &   \alpha  &   1+\alpha\\
1       &   1       &   0       &   1+\alpha&   \alpha  \\
\alpha  &   \alpha  &   1+\alpha&   0       &   1       \\
1+\alpha&   1+\alpha&   \alpha  &   1       &   0       \\
\end{array}$$

$$\begin{array}{c|cccc}
\times  &   \color{grey}{0}       &   1       &   \alpha  &   1+\alpha\\ \hline
\color{grey}{0}       &   \color{grey}{0}       &   \color{grey}{0}       &   \color{grey}{0}       &   \color{grey}{0}       \\
1       &   \color{grey}{0}       &   1       &   \alpha  &   1+\alpha\\
\alpha  &   \color{grey}{0}       &   \alpha  &   1+\alpha&   1       \\
1+\alpha&   \color{grey}{0}       &   1+\alpha&   1       &   \alpha  \\
\end{array}$$

You can see that $\mathbb{F}_4$ is a group under addition and $\mathbb{F}_4^\times=\mathbb{F}_4\setminus \{0\}$ is a group under multiplication.

In this case, I made $\mathbb{F}_4=\mathbb{F}_{2^2}$ out of the polynomial $x^2+x+1$, which is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_2$.  I get the multiplication table by taking all polynomials of degree $1$ or less (i.e. below the degree of the irreducible polynomial minus one), then multiplying them together and reducing them mod $x^2+x+1$. (For calculation, it doesn't matter whether you use $x$ or $\alpha$.)

Comment: This example shows existence but not uniqueness, no?

Comment: @leonbloy yup, uniqueness is more complicated, I don't endeavor to fit it in an MSE answer

Comment: " Every finite field is isomorphic to $\mathcal{F}_{p^n}$", does that mean that up to isomorphism, there is only one finite field of cardinality $p^n$? Thanks!

Comment: @user110320 Sure does

Answer (score 11):

No. As the wikipage linked to by Jack explains there is a unique (up to isomorphism) finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$ with $q$ elements whenever $q=p^n$ is a power of a prime $p$ ($n$ a positive integer).

The simplest example is $\mathbb{F}_4$. It has elements $\{0,1,\alpha,1+\alpha\}$, where $\alpha$ is a mysterious constant that satisfies the equation
$$\alpha^2=\alpha+1.\qquad(*)$$
For all $x\in\mathbb{F}_4$ we have $x+x=0$. This explains everything there is to know about the addition in $\mathbb{F}_4$, so for example
$$
\alpha+(1+\alpha)=1+(\alpha+\alpha)=1+0=1.
$$
That mysterious equation $(*)$ explains everything you need to know about multiplication in $\mathbb{F}_4$ (together with ring axioms). So for example
$$
\alpha(1+\alpha)=\alpha+\alpha^2=\alpha+(1+\alpha)=1.
$$
This means that $\alpha$ and $1+\alpha$ are (multiplicative) inverses to each other. From this it follows easily that $\mathbb{F}_4$ is, indeed, a field.

An exercise for you: Show that $x^3=1$ for all non-zero elements $x\in\mathbb{F}_4$.

Comment: Is there some special property of finite fields which gives a shorter or more elegant solution to the exercise than "By Lagrange's theorem"?

Comment: @Peter: Well, many of us will identify $$x^2+x+1$$ as the third cyclotomic polynomial at a glance. That does imply the claim of the exercise, but isn't really special to finite fields. My goal with the exercise was simply to make the OP use the relation $(*)$ at least once. Just to get a feel of how the arithmetic in $\mathbb{F}_4$ works.

Answer (score 7):

Not quite.

> There is a finite field with $q$ elements, iff $q=p^k$ for some prime $p$. This field is unique up to isomorphy.

So finite fields with a prime number of elements are indeed isomorphic to $F_p$.

But there are also fields with a prime power number of elements, usually also denoted by $F_q$ where $q=p^k$, $k>1$. They can be constructed as following: 
$$F_q\simeq F_p[X]/(f(X))$$
where $f\in F_p[X]$ is an irreducible polynomial of degree $k$. This construction does not depend on the choice of  $f$, as different polynomials (of the same degree) lead to isomorphic fields.

Comment: I am supposing you meant polynomials of different degree lead to different isomorphic fields.

Comment: What I mean is $F_p[X]/f\simeq F_p[X]/g$, if $f,g$ are irreducible polynomials of degree $k$. Is the formulation above ambiguous?

Comment: I think I misread that as: Different polynomials lead to different  fields. My apologies. But I suppose saying that by different polynomials you mean different polynomials of the same degree would make it more clear.

Comment: @SouparnaPurohit: Thank you, I edited it accordingly.

Answer (score 6):

No, every finite field is isomorphic to $\mathbb F_q$ where $q = p^n$ for some prime $p$ and non-negative integer $n$.

Answer (score 6):

No, not all finite fields are isomorphic to a field of prime cardinality. What is however true is that the cardinality of a finite field is always a power of a prime. And, up to isomorphism there is a unique field of cardinality $q$ for each prime power $q$.