# How many subfields of order $p^m$ in $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields

We know there is exists a subfield of order  $p^m$ in $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ if $m$ divides $n$. My questions is if $m$ does not divide $n$, is there still such a subfield? And how many subfields are there for each $m|n$?

Comment: These questions have been answered many times on our site. Anyway, the answers are *No!* and *1*, respectively.

Comment: To see why that subfield of order $p^m$ is unique up to isomorphism, see [Are all finite fields isomorphic to $F_p$
?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/456703/are-all-finite-fields-isomorphic-to-mathbbf-p)

Comment: I know they are isomorphic if the orders are the same. But can there be multiple subfields of the same order in $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$?

Answer (score 0):

$\operatorname{Gal}(\Bbb F_{p^n}/\Bbb F_p) = \Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$

Using the [Fundamental theorem of Galois theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_Galois_theory), one sees that there is only one such subfield if $m \mid n$, and zero otherwise.

---

A more elementary proof that the existence of a subfield of order $p^m$ implies $m \mid n$ is to note that if $E$ is such a subfield, then $m = [E : \Bbb F_p] \mid [\Bbb F_{p^n} : E] [E : \Bbb F_p] = [\Bbb F_{p^n} : \Bbb F_p] = n$.

Comment: I know they are isomorphic if the orders are the same. But can there be multiple subfields of the same order in $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$?

Comment: No, because there is only one subgroup of $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ of size $\dfrac n m$.